How to create a page aligned variable in a kernel module?
So I want to have a buffer in my kernel module that I created like that:
static char buf[BUF_LEN];

My problem is that the start address of this buffer is not necessarily page aligned. To give a bit of context: I want to extract the physical address (I currently do so using virt_to_phys, although I have read somewhere that it is not appliccable to variable addresses in kernel modules; is there a better way?). Then I change execution environment with a hypervisor call to execute svsm; the specifics don't really matter here. This new execution environment has the same (emulated) physical address space and the process there will read the physical address of buf. The problem is: it expects it to be page aligned!
Is there a good way to create a page aligned buffer and its physical address within a kernel module?


static char buf[BUF_LEN];

That already sounds like a potential bug to me :) Your module has a static buffer of some size defined in a global scope, meaning: there's exactly one of such buffers, and it must exist for the whole module lifetime. If you now need to exchange data with two VMs, how do you do that?
So, nope, you need to go for kmalloc if you want buffers of any significant size that don't live on the stack (i.e., only live for the lifetime of function call), and you need to save their address (and if they are variably-sized, their size) in the struct that describes your VM.

although I have read somewhere that it is not appliccable to variable addresses in kernel modules

Nothing specific about kernel modules, this is basic C: local variables, parameters, temporary results,… need not have a memory address, because there's no need for them to have one.
if you assumed everything you declared in C had an address, you need to be very careful with your code: that's a fallacy! Might make sense to brush up your formal knowledge of C, as annoying as that sounds, with a book, when you do memory handling-intense jobs like shuffling memory between hypervisors and VMs.

Ok for clarification: I don't have two VMs. It is a different execution context within the same VM, sharing the same emulated physical memory space. So if I have this static (global) buffer, is it on the stack anyways? I thought it would be in a different, globally defined segment, thus outliving the function call. I need to be able to read from the buffer at a later point in time. I currently solved it with kmalloc and virt_to_phys, but I need to copy between the buffer and the kmalloc'd buffer; which I'd like to avoid.

For more information on what I'm doing: I work with svsm that use some hardware features of AMD Epyc to create confidential virtual machines in the cloud. It's a module that loads at a higher privilege than the Linux kernel; to get from the Linux kernel to SVSM, one needs a context switch within the VM, that can be requested from the hypervisor. So it's like "Please run this VM at privilege level X" to the HV. And there I need to get the physical address from Linux to SVSM

you need to use kmalloc if you need mapped memory, full stop – where the buffer resides when you define it as global static is up to the compiler, essentially. And really, a kernel module needs to be able to clean up its own memory allocations: so, kmalloc in your init, free it in your de-init. And again, keep the pointer around in a data structure that describes the state of what you're doing in your module. Don't clutter state all over the place
